# Attach features of lines to points

Tags: qgis, point, line, attribute-joins, network

I am trying to calculate the cost of network to homes. In the image i have cable (brown line) between utility boxes(pink/blue points) and home feed (black dash) to the home.
I know the cost for each element (line, point) but i want to attach this cost to the homes it goes on to feed (tree branch)or attached the home ID to the features Is what im describing doable?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance use the ***NNJoin*** plugin, with the point layer as *input layer* and the line layer as *join layer*.  A new point layer will be created, with the points and their attributes from the input point layer plus the attributes of the nearest line and a new `distance` attribute that contains the distance to the line.

Here it is assumed that you would like to get the attribute of the closest line added to the attributes of a point. If it is point to nearest other point, you use the other point layer instead of the line layer.

This is just nearest neighbour. If you want something else you probably need to look into network analysis.